# mysql - Average from 2 field, ignoring zero

Tags: mysql, average

I am looking for an elegant query to get an average ignoring zero values.

Example: I have 2 values, and an expected result:

```
SELECT X(10,20) AS result
-- expected result: 15

SELECT X(0,20) AS result
-- expected result: 20

SELECT X(10,0) AS result
-- expected result: 10

SELECT X(0,0) AS result
-- expected result: NULL
```

This is my attempt:

```
(val1+val2)/(2-IF(val1,0,1)-IF(val2,0,1))
```

Any better way to do it?

thank you

Comment: For an expression using only builtin MySQL functions, that's about as good as it's going to get. One small tweak: you could add the values in the denominator, rather than subtracting them from from 2.  e.g.   **`(val1+val2)/(IF(val1,1,0)+IF(val2,1,0))`**

Comment: @spencer7593 , thats a good idea to make it shorter!

Comment: I don't see anyway to make it more elegant. My preference for the `ABS(SIGN())` pattern is probably due to two things: **1)** handling of NULL values. With `ABS(SIGN())`, we can get back 0, 1 or NULL. With the IF() function, we are only going to get back a 0 or 1. (Just choose the one that best meets your specification.)  and **2)** a holdover from my earlier days... Oracle didn't have a slick IF() function. My tendency was to go with expressions and functions (where practical) that were available in DB2, Teradata and Oracle.  (And the SIGN trick was really handy in an Oracle `DECODE`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write it like this:

```
( val1 + val2 )/( ABS(SIGN(val1)) + ABS(SIGN(val2)) )
```

I believe that's equivalent to the OP expresssion, which already looks about as elegant as it's going to get without creating a user-defined function.

(It's really just my personal preference to avoid the subtraction from the constant "2". And the extra "1" and "0" constants.)

If I had to extend this expression to three arguments:

```
( val1 + val2 + val3)/( ABS(SIGN(val1)) + ABS(SIGN(val2)) + ABS(SIGN(val3)) )
```

NOTES:

The MySQL `SIGN` function will return an integer value representing the "sign" of a numeric value: `-1`, `0`, `1` or `NULL`.

The MySQL `ABS` function will return the absolute value of a number, so wrapping that around SIGN function, i.e. `ABS(SIGN(n))` the return will be `0`, `1` or `NULL`. `SIGN(ABS(n))` would return the same thing.

If one of the arguments is NULL, this expression will return NULL. Just like the OP expression does.

I'm not sure that is any more elegant. But that's how I would do it.

---

If the intent is to make the SQL shorter, to specify `val1` and `val2` only once, as in the OP examples, that require a function. MySQL doesn't provide a native builtin function for that, so we would have to define (create) a user-defined function.

But if we did that, we would need to specify the datatypes of the arguments and the datatype of the return (e.g. `BIGINT`, `DECIMAL(M,N)`, `DOUBLE`, etc.) and whichever way we go with that, it will have potential for implicit datatype conversions and rounding/imprecision.

Without a user defined function, `val1` and `val2` have to be included in the expression two times. But I think that's better than the four or five times each in some of the other proposed expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` to treat the cases where one of the columns is `0` specially before averaging.

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN val1 = 0 AND val2 = 0 THEN NULL
        WHEN val1 = 0 OR val2 = 0 THEN val1 + val2
        ELSE (val1+val2)/2
       END AS avg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when val1 = 0 and val2= 0 then null
                 when val1 = 0 and val2 ! = 0 then val2
                 when val1 != 0 and val2= 0 then val1
                 else (val1 + val2 ) /2 
               end avg
```

try to modify according to your requirement or mysql version